# How to make high smooth, high resolution particle motion animations

Tags: r, animation, ffmpeg

For some time I have been having trouble with producing short movies/animations/gifs which are of sufficiently high resolution. I'm going to use R to generate some frames as a random example, but if there is somewhere else I should be creating frames from to give better results I would be interested in that too.

### Creating frames

The kinds of animations I'm interested involve some cloud of 'particles' moving about the page. There are usually a large number of particles and I would like their motion be as smooth as possible. As a random example, consider the R code (using base graphics and not `ggplot2` as it is far quicker for saving a large number of frames)

```
N <- 500
nFrames <- 250
points <- pracma::randp(n=N, r=1)
rot <- function(p, a) { return(cbind(p[,1]*cos(a) - p[,2]*sin(a), p[,1]*sin(a) + p[,2]*cos(a))) }
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "green", "blue"))(nFrames)
ang <- seq(0, pi, length=N)

# Save frames
png(filename="%d.png")
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
for (i in seq(1,N,length=nFrames)) 
        plot(sqrt(i)*rot(points, ang[i]), xlim=sqrt(N)*c(-1,1),  ylim=sqrt(N)*c(-1,1), cex=0.5, pch=19, col=cols[i], asp=1, xaxs="i")

dev.off()
```

### Frames to animation

There are a number of tools available to chain each frame together into an animation (in R there are also things like `gganimate` which I have tried but did not find convenient or better than the following). I also don't have any requirements for the resulting file size or time taken to get everything looking as crisp as possible.

#### convert

For short gif style animations a common solution is to do something like `convert -delay 1 -loop 0 *.png g.gif` which gives

[image]

#### gifski

Running `gifski -o g.gif *.png` produces

[image: boring_gif]

There is an annoying amount of 'jitter' happening in the transition between frames in both of the above (though less noticeable with `gifski`).

#### ffmpeg

Being gifs, the above will be have limited options for tweaking so I suspect part of the solution lies in using `ffmpeg`. All I would like to know is how to make the animation appear totally smooth without any kind of noticeable blurriness. Here the resulting movies tend to be quite smooth, but resolution is lacking.. e.g. after setting `height=1080` and `width=1080` in `png()` of the above code we can run

```
fmpeg -i %d.png -s 1080x1080 -c:v libx264 -vf fps=250 -pix_fmt yuv444p out.mp4
```

If the particles move on a time/space scale smaller than is visible to the naked eye, and we set the frames per second to be the total number of frames, the transition between frames should be seamless, right? At around the 2 second mark in `out.mp4` you will see some kind of frame drop and similarly right at the beginning. Why does this happen?

#### Questions

1. Is there a standard documented approach to generating high quality animations/movies involving large numbers of 'point-like' particles? Do we need more an more frames?
2. How to improve resolution of movies using `ffmpeg`? Should I change from .png format to something vectorised (if so, how)?

Running Fedora v31.

Comment: What is width x height of the PNG files?

Comment: When using `gifski` and `convert` I did not specify height/width. For `ffmpeg` I found better results when specifying the dimensions in the `png()` function since `ffmpeg` accepts the `-s` option. I used `height=width=1080` in that case and for no particular reason. For the actual application I am considering I need rectangular dimensions, not square. Why?

Comment: I meant the input PNG files, not the output. I asked because you mentioned "resolution is lacking", and I wanted to see if you were upscaling (which is bad).

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into what that means exactly.. I was hoping that I could adapt `ffmpeg` options to whatever size I set the png's to be. The larger the images, the longer to form a clear video from them right?

Comment: Let me rephrase. If your PNG images are 480x480, and you tell ffmpeg to make it 1080x1080, then you are upscaling and it will look blurry. Instead, make them 1080x1080 with whatever tool you used to make the PNG images, then use ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks I understand. Yes, I was not upscaling in the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 250 -i %d.png -c:v libx264rgb -crf 0 out.mp4
```

- The video will be playable by FFmpeg-based players (VLC, mpv, ffplay, etc).
- This avoids scaling and will output the same width x height as the input PNG files.
- Default frame rate for the image demuxer is 25, so `-framerate` is used to overrule that.
- Colorspace is preserved.
- Output is lossless.